# full width border line and transparent logo goes over

Tags: html, css, layout

I though it would be the best by adding an image of what I'm trying to do here.

What I need is to have a line (just a visual thing for users) to separate header div and content div but same time the logo should sit right on that line.

When I add `border-bottom: 5px solid #ff0000;` to `header_wrap` then obviously the line becomes visible in transparent logo so it looks like the logo being over-lined! That is the only problem I'm having.

Any way of doing what I need?

Background of logo **HAS TO BE** transparent because header and page body will have images as background.

Thanks in advance

[image: the result I need is this]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        *
        {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }

        /*** HEADER *************************************************************/

        #header_wrap
        {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            height: 115px;
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            z-index:1;
            border-bottom: 8px solid #e61923;
        }
        #header_centered_content
        {
            width: 850px;
            height: 115px;
            margin: 0 auto 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        #logo
        {
            width: 229px;
            height: 49px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 76px;
            background-image:url(images/logo-top.png);
        }

        /*** BODY *************************************************************/

        #body_wrap
        {
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            height:355px;
            margin-top:150px;
        }

        #body_centered_content
        {
            width: 850px;
            margin: 0 auto 0;
            position: relative;
        }   
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header_wrap">
        <div id="header_centered_content">
            <div id="logo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="body_wrap">
        <div id="body_centered_content">
            A lot of TEXT !!!
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your css and logo image link

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1: recreate the logo with a white background

2: put the logo in a container with a white background, for example another div

3: if you have the logo as the background image of the div, also set the background color to white.

all of the above use: "background-color: white;" or background-color:#ffffff;"

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute` to place the `divs` one on the another.

And add background color as white to the div which contains logo image.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header_wrap">
        <div id="header_centered_content">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
   <div class="logo"><img src="http://redframe.com/mediakit/horz/black_bg/Redframe_Logo_Black_100.png" /></div>
    </div>

    <div id="body_wrap">
        <div id="body_centered_content">
            A lot of TEXT !!!
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header_wrap{width:100%; position:relative; height:150px; border:green solid 1px}
#header_centered_content{position:absolute; top:41%; border-bottom:5px solid #ff0000; height:5px; width:100%}
.logo{position:absolute; top:38%; left:40%; background:#fff}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YNJst/1/)**

Comment: Logo has to be transparent. Header and main body have it's own image as background.

Comment: Changing them image bg color only in the middle is the only solution now